# Web Application Designer Position - What should we be looking for?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, yui, designer

I work for a small data management/warehousing company that also focuses heavily on web applications.  We are looking to "beautify" our existing web apps into something along the lines of mint.com or sifterapp.com or any of the 37signals sites for example.  We are a .Net shop so whatever framework used on the front end would need to play nice with a .net back end and also use asp.net.

My question is what skills should we be looking for and what is the proper title for a person that knows how to create very nice looking web applications like the ones I've mentioned?  I think having some experience with photoshop is always necessary, but it seems like a lot of the design patterns can be done using css and/or other front end technologies, or am I off base here?  Basically, what skills should we be looking for in a candidate if we are looking for them to have skills in creating beautiful web apps that are both very nice looking and also very usable and what is that position called?  Web developer?  Designer?  UI Engineer?  Web Experience Designer?

I am also aware of some UI oriented frameworks like YUI, is this something that we should be looking for in a candidate, experience with this?  Is a likely candidate going to be someone with a graphic design/artist degree or will it be someone more programming oriented?  Is this actually a task for 2 separate people, one doing the graphics and another doing the user experience/css layout?  It just seems very confusing to figure out what exactly we should be looking for so the interviews have been rather hit and miss so far.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd get a better response from the UI Stackexchange site.

Comment: cool, will try there! thanks a lot Russell.

Answer (score 1):

you need a *Graphic Artist*, a *usability expert* and a *web developer*.

it is rare/unlikely that you will find one person who excels at all three

the good news is that you'll only need the graphic artist and usability people short-term

Comment: Thanks Steve.  Yea this is sort of good and bad news. Going to have to do some thinking about this, I decided to also pose the question over at ui.stackexchange

Comment: hm. i didn't know i was so rare. zv2010, if you're still looking, check me out :)

Answer (score 0):

I would look for a Javascript developer with experience in integrating with ASP.NET. You need to explicitly require experience with CSS layouts, Javascript, frameworks such as jQuery, Prototype, etc. I know a lot of people that are ASP.NET developers and think they are good web developers just because they can drop a few controls on a page and have no understanding of what is happening on the client-side. Also, make sure that they provide you a portfolio.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, yea I totally agree that ASP.NET developers are a totally different breed than Web Designers/Graphics Artists and even Usability Experience experts.  As a small company we sort of need a hybrid of all 3 but if that's not reasonable then of course we can't do that.  Do you think we will need a hardcore CSS/XHTML/JQuery expert web designer paired with a .NET developer (to handle all the WCF, data access calls, front-end data logic) to get something like this done?  Since it is so data-centric (relies on understanding business objects in c#) how do we bridge that gap?

Answer (score 0):

There are almost always 3 parts of a website:

1.) Design: The designer(s) is(are) planning the layout of the website, with the following in mind:
- maximalization of usability
- nice looking
- using only needed components (no elements to "fill the void")
2.) Backend: The backend guy(s) is(are) working on the functionality of the server
3.) Frontend: The frontend guy(s) is(are) working on the frontend

The backend and frontend guy might be one person, but programmers are code writers (with no artistic inclination), designers are artists. If you put a designer to write code (for example CSS), he might not solve the problems well enough, the same is the situation if you put a programmer to make a design. In my opinion you should hire a designer (some designers work for a very low salary) and a programmer.

In my opinion nobody can honestly say that he/she is a good backend and frontend developer and a good designer in the same time. For example I'm a good backend guy, a decent frontend guy, but I'm not a designer.

Comment: Yea I think with web apps it goes even further, in terms of usability since it isn't just simply a webSITE, it's a web APP, so there are definitely different patterns there just like when designing a regular windows application, some of the usability concerns need to be addressed.  I think web applications are less graphics intensive since other than a logo and icons, there isn't a ton of graphics on a web app afaik, but I could be wrong.

Comment: So I think as Steven pointed out, maybe we need to look at it from 3 angles, a designer (knows graphics and how to really make things pretty from an overall design standpoint), a css/xhtml/jquery expert who knows how to layout the design and implement it from a front end code perspective, then a traditional asp.net coder that knows how to hook everything up from a complicated back end architecture.  Even with an abstracted business layer, the UI will still need to hook into the APIs to get to the data (wcf, web services, traditional api, etc.)